# Error when trying to verify a signature with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl, rsa, digital-signature

I have a `file.txt`, a `cert.pem` and a `file.sign`. 
After extracting the public key from `cert.pem` into `pubkey.pem` I use the following command to verify the `file.sign` and see if it matches the `file.txt`:

`x590 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem -out pubkey.pem  // Extract pubkey`

`dgst -sha256 -verify pubkey.pem -signature file.sign file.txt // Verify signature`

I have the error :

```
Verification failure
error in dgst
```

If the signature just did not match the data `file.txt`, the `error in dgst`would not be printed would it ? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0):

At least in version OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips, the '-pubkey' option to the 'openssl x509' command outputs the key to stdout. It does not get written to the file indicated by the '-out' argument.
Try:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
```

Comment: `unknown parameter >` I have been using `-out` just fine until now and `>`has always raised an error

Comment: Supplying details about the OS (distribution, version) and applications involved (version, installed from source or package) is always helpful. On Ubuntu Linux 16.04.2 LTS with Openssl 1.0.2k, the line I suggested executes successfully. `$ openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem > pubkey.pem
$ cat pubkey.pem 
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8ASI8yu0JwiAgfbiBOvRqpb93
liNVQI9vpTOKZiblj8qrd/x5T6hmi6c/6xQLfcnbopKAvatstL+hjdH91WY2lSak
H8ZqRdHS+2zdPhLETQZyBkyBkuWVddZ5wx5VzRhZz2ijryd+QaU6QE2xPID6lw0S
3s5xp0lsNlRkINmp0QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
$ `

Comment: FYI - I prefer to use the `openssl smime` command for encrypt, decrypt, sign, and verify functionality.